# MS Access Query Calculate Field

Tags: mysql, ms-access, ms-query

- I got a table StockMovements which records all movements of my
  products. It has a field named "Status", which can have either the
  value Sold or Purchased, Quantity and Product (there are few more but
  arent important now).
- I made a query to take all the products with the status "Purchased"
  and to take the quantity and named it Purchased Products (From the
  table StockMovements). I have just sum the quantity and got the
  purchased quantity for the each product (named the field Purchased).
- I made another query, all the same just with the Status of Sold.
- After I made a new query with the name Stock. Its built of the table
  Products and the 2 queries I mentioned above. It takes the prodict_ID
  and the product name from the table Product, the purchased field from
  the first query and the Sold field from the second query and then a
  final field not connected to any of above but a calculation. Named it
  AvailableQuantity and added next with expression builder to it
  =[Purchased] - [Sold].
- Now when I run the query it works fine, except one thing. When I have
  a specific quantity of a purchased product which I havent sold to
  anyone yet (not even 1 piece) it doesnt want to show up in the query.
- I want the product to show in the query and that the available
  quantity is the purchased quantity. So somehow to skip the Sold value
  if its 0 and just to write the Purchased quantity to that field.

Answer (score 0):

When you have no sold qty your sum effectively becomes Purchased-Null which will result in no answer.

You should allow for nulls by using [Purchased] - (Nz([Sold],0)) which will force a zero into the calculation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried it, but it still doesn't want to show it, however, the calculation still works good, so I assume that the function is ok.

Comment: Is there a way to write in the criteria for product_ID to show them all no matter what?

Answer (score 0):

I went into the SQL view and changed the INNER JOIN to RIGHT JOIN, it did the job.

```js
SELECT tblProduct.Product_ID, tblProduct.ProductName, Nz([Purchased],0) AS
PurchasedQuantity, Nz([Sold],0) AS SoldQuantity, [PurchasedQuantity]-(Nz([SoldQuantity],0)) 
AS [Available] FROM qrySoldProducts RIGHT JOIN (qryPurchasedProducts RIGHT JOIN 
tblProduct ON qryPurchasedProducts.Product_ID = tblProduct.Product_ID) ON 
qrySoldProducts.Product_ID = tblProduct.Product_ID;
```